# IIS Multiple SSL certificates with overlapping expiry dates

Tags: ssl, iis

My predecessor bought a new SSL certificate before he left and installed it into IIS. The current certificate is about to expire but that is the one that is linked to our website.

So the question is when the current certificate expires will the other certificate automatically kick in or will I need to modify the site and the select the new certificate in the dropdown box.  If I have to do this, will it cause any issues with the running website. Will I need to restart IIS. Should I do it in the maintenance window.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The certificate will not automatically transition. If the new cert is already installed, you need to go into the Website Bindings in IIS (Right click on the website and select "Bindings") and select the new certificate. It will not restart IIS. The change will be instantaneous (so if you make a mistake, it can break things - insert disclaimer that if it's a critical site, maintenance windows are always safer).